# how to convert data csv in python using dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

i have dataframe like this..

```
0    [4, 1, 0, 0, 1]
1    [0, 1, 0, 0, 2]
```

when i convert use my code

```
ok=open('data/data_cluster.csv','a')
write=csv.writer(ok)
write.writerows([df2['centroid']])
ok.close()
```

the result CSV data like this

```
[4 1 0 0 1],[0 1 0 0 2]
```

the result should be like this

```
4,1,0,0,1
0,1,0,0,2
```

please help me...

Comment: Looks like you have a series and not a data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a `pd.Series`. Make it a data frame first

```
pd.DataFrame(s.tolist()).to_csv('file.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

where `s` is your series. Could be your `df2['centroid']`

Answer (score 0):

You are working on pandas dataframe, so just use pandas `to_csv` to write to csv as follows. The saved file will have line breaks as you want

```
df2['centroid'].to_csv('data/data_cluster.csv', index=False)
```